# Solution verification, complex inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification

$$\{z\in \text{complex numbers :}\quad|z| + Re(z) \leq Im \}$$
$Re...\text{real component}$

$Im... \text{imaginary component}$

$$|x + iy| + x \leq y$$
$$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + x \leq y $$
$$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq y -x $$
$$1.1: \text{for } y \leq x $$
$$ 0 \leq -2xy \leftrightarrow 0\geq xy$$
$$\text{solution 1 : }\, y \geq 0 \,\text{ and }\, x\leq 0$$
$$1.2 \text{ for }\,y\geq x $$
$$ xy \geq 0$$
$$\text{solution 2: }x\geq 0 \, \text{ and }y\geq 0\text{ and } y \leq x  $$
$$\text{Final solution: Solution 1 union Solution 2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le y-x\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}x^2+y^2\le (y-x)^2\\ y\ge x\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} xy\le 0\\ y\ge x\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\\\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}x=0\\ y\ge x\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}x<0\\ y>0\\ y\ge x\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}x>0\\ y<0\\ y\ge x\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}y=0\\ y\ge x\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}x=0\\ y\ge 0\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}x<0\\ y>0\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}y=0\\ x\le0\end{cases}$$

So the solution set is the closed II quadrant, i.e. the set defined by the condition $[x\le0\land y\ge 0]$.

Comment: When we square (y - x) do we have to do it for two different situations, if it's more or less than zero, or does the inequality not turn around?

Comment: The rules are that $$\sqrt A\le B\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}B\ge 0\\ A\ge 0\\ A\le B^2\end{cases}\\ \sqrt A\ge B\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}A\ge 0\\ B<0\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}A\ge 0\\ B\ge 0\\ A\ge B^2\end{cases}$$
In other words, $\sqrt A\le B$ needs the condition $B\ge0$ to be added before squaring, whereas $\sqrt A\ge B$ has the case $B<0$ included without further evaluation, and the case $B\ge0$ inspected with the additional condition $A\ge B^2$.